@solana/wallet-standard-... libraries has no valid source code in git repo (repo has no functions which provided in npm library)
Hey guys is somewhere last version source code of @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-react because source code in npm repo for old version i think. There is no a lot of functions which exist in npm repo. Maybe solana can give access. Ty for answers

Is my answer below what you needed, @Timur? If so, click that ‘accept’ checkmark, when you have a chance.

This was my fault; I mistook the @anza-xyz/wallet-adapter repo for @wallet-standard/wallet-standard and force-pushed over top of it.
The source code has since been restored.
